# aggregate all keys(deep) of json

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, jsonb, greenplum

i have a table like this (9,000,000row/day)(2,000,000row/country)
partition by data_date->country(sub_partition)

[image]
(markdown has a problem,i can't submit this table,so->image)

i want to aggregate by all the keys of category_tree to sum sold
like this

| category_id | data_date | sum_sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2022-07-10 | 53 |
| b | 2022-07-10 | 53 |
| c | 2022-07-10 | 53 |
| d | 2022-07-10 | 28 |
| e | 2022-07-10 | 20 |

i must get the different level of category and last 7 or more days(data_date) on in once select

i used the sql like this

```
    SELECT 'a' AS category_id, data_date, sum(sold) AS sum_sold
    FROM table
    WHERE CAST((category_tree::jsonb#>'{"a"}') AS jsonb) IS NOT NULL 
    AND data_date>= '2022-07-01' 
    AND data_date <= '2022-07-09'
    GROUP BY data_date
    UNION ALL
```

or this

but this sql can't get different level of category

```
    SELECT jsonb_object_keys(category_tree::jsonb#>'{"a", "b"}') as category_id, 
    data_date, sum(sold) AS sum_sold 
    FROM table 
    WHERE data_date>= '2022-07-01' 
    AND data_date <= '2022-07-09' 
    AND CAST((category_tree::jsonb#>'{"a", "b", "c"}') AS jsonb) IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY data_date
```

but by the way i have to face two problems with ''union all'->

1.too many range table entries

2.ERROR:  at most 50 slices are allowed in a query, current number: 177
HINT:  rewrite your query or adjust GUC gp_max_slices

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive `cte` with [`json_each`](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tanzu-Greenplum/6/greenplum-database/GUID-ref_guide-function-summary.html):

```
with recursive cte(d, k, v, s) as (
   select c.data_date, v.key, v.value, c.sold from countries c cross join json_each(c.category_tree) v
   union all
   select c.d, v.key, v.value, c.s from cte c cross join json_each(c.v) v
)
select c.k, min(c.d), sum(c.s) from cte c group by c.k order by c.k
```